# Order neo4j cypher query by node depth

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have the following graph:

[image: graph]

I want to return all users which have the `CAN_DISTRIBUTE` `Credits` permission attached through a `Role` which `APPLIES_ON` a `Group`.

The following query returns both `sara` and `admin` as user names:

`MATCH (users)-[:IS]->()<-[:CHILD_OF*0..]-(roles)-[:CAN_DISTRIBUTE]->(asset:Asset{name:"Credits"}),
      (roles)-[:APPLIES_ON]->(group:Group{name:"Digital"})
WITH DISTINCT users
RETURN collect(users.name)`

Now, I'm having a really hard time to order the users returned by their `Role` relationship depth. I want `sara` to be returned first as the `Manager` role is a child of `SuperManager`.
In english it's like saying, give me all the users which can distribute credits on group X, ordered by their role hierarchy.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Here is the query to create this graph:

`CREATE (admin:User{name:"admin"})
CREATE (sara:User{name:"sara"})
CREATE (c:Asset{name:"Credits"})
CREATE (marketing:Group{name:"Marketing"})
CREATE (digital:Group{name:"Digital"})
CREATE (super_manager:Role{name:"SuperManager"})
CREATE (manager:Role{name:"Manager"})
CREATE (manager)-[:CAN_DISTRIBUTE]->(c)
CREATE (admin)-[:IS]->(super_manager)
CREATE (sara)-[:IS]->(manager)
CREATE (super_manager)-[:APPLIES_ON]->(marketing)
CREATE (super_manager)-[:APPLIES_ON]->(digital)
CREATE (manager)-[:APPLIES_ON]->(marketing)
CREATE (manager)-[:APPLIES_ON]->(digital)
CREATE (manager)-[:CHILD_OF]->(super_manager)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the length of the entire path, this way:

```
MATCH p = (users)-[:IS]->()<-[:CHILD_OF*0..]-(roles)-[:CAN_DISTRIBUTE]->(asset:Asset{name:"Credits"}),
      (roles)-[:APPLIES_ON]->(group:Group{name:"Digital"})
WITH DISTINCT users, length(p) as pathLength
RETURN users.name
ORDER BY pathLength
```

The output for the given data set:

```
╒════════════╕
│"users.name"│
╞════════════╡
│"sara"      │
├────────────┤
│"admin"     │
└────────────┘
```

Comment: you just saved my day :) Thank you!

Comment: The `DISTINCT` directive seems to not be working properly when I add the `CAN_DISTRIBUTE` permission on the `SuperManager` role directly http://d.pr/i/6owUQB Do you have any ideas why? It returns 2 times the user `admin`.

Comment: I'm thinking about how to solve It, but it occurs because when you add `CAN_DISTRIBUTE` directly to `SuperManager` you are creating two possible paths between `admin` and `:Group{name:"Digital"}`. You can see it more clearly running: `MATCH p = (users)-[:IS]->()<-[:CHILD_OF*0..]-(roles)-[:CAN_DISTRIBUTE]->(asset:Asset{name:"Credits"}),
      (roles)-[:APPLIES_ON]->(group:Group{name:"Digital"})
RETURN DISTINCT users, length(p) as pathLength`

Comment: Right, just to give you the reason why i want to add that relationship explicitely. It's because i don't know how to write a query which says "give me all users which CAN_DISTRIBUTE credits through a Role which APPLIES_ON some Group". If the relationship does not exists between super manager and the credits node, it won't return me the admin as part of the result. Not Sure if it's clear, maybe you have a solution for this as well.

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois this should work: `MATCH (u:User)-[:IS]->(r1:Role)<-[:CHILD_OF*0..]-(r2:Role)-[:CAN_DISTRIBUTE]->(asset:Asset{name:"Credits"})
WHERE (r1)-[:APPLIES_ON]->(:Group{name:"Digital"}) OR (r2)-[:APPLIES_ON]->(:Group{name:"Digital"})
RETURN u`, but I believe this query can be improved.

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois I'm trying to make some improvements.

Comment: it still returns the admin twice unfortunately :-/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154914/discussion-between-bruno-peres-and-pierre-louis-gottfrois).